# What is the performance of Collections.binarySearch over manually searching a list?

Tags: java, collections

I would like to know the which one to use. I have a list of students. I want to search a student with his name. Till now I was doing it manually by iterating the list like below

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Student student = list.get(i);
    if(student.getName().equals(studentNameIWantToSearch)) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}

Student student = list.get(index);
//my logic from here
```

Recently I saw a method named `binarySearch(List<? extends T> list, T key, Comparator<? super T> c)` from `Collections` class. I read about this. In order perform a binary search, the list has to be sorted and the has to be passed to `binarySearch` method as an argument.

Now, what if I don't want to sort the list? Because I don't need sorting on it. I see sorting as an additional overhead on my logic.

Can anyone please tell me why should I use binary search instead of manually searching. I know that binary search takes O(log n) time. Manually searching it takes O(n). I am concerned about the sorting also. Sorting the whole list also takes some time. Unfortunately I don't know what algorithm does java uses. I hope java uses the best available algorithm for sorting. But still I want to know.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You use binary search if the cost of searching outweighs the cost of sorting (e.g. lots of searching on an unchanging list). Profiling first would be a good idea though. You can find details about the sorting algorithms Java uses on the javadoc for the sort methods.

Comment: suggestions a) profile itself and see b) unless your student list is huge - why stress about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binary search is way faster than normal search.

Suppose you have a list with 11 elements: `a, c, d, f, g, j, m, p, r, s, z`. Your for loop to iterate over the elements, with a minimum of 1 iteration and a maximum of 11 iterations, which makes an average of 5.5 iterations to find an element. Now let's try to pick `r` from the list. The way binary search works is this: pick the middle element (in our case `j`). `r` > `j`, thus `r`'s index is greater than `j`'s. Let's do it again, the middle element from `m` to `z`. That's `r`, we're already there.

You see that we have less iterations, by average. Per iteration, a half of the elements remain.

That's the advantage of binary search. The drawback is that the list must be sorted. So if you change the list a lot, then you need to sort the inserted element, and then using binary search might be too 'expensive'. Otherwise, if you search a lot, you might want to use binary search.

Comment: Suppose I have 500 elements. The operations taken to sort is 500 log 500. Now I am searching for the element. Its log 500. The total operations are 500 * 2.x + 2.x. Where as, if I am linearly searching it is 500 operations. What I understand is, if the list is always changing, I have to go for linear searching. If the searching is more and with a less frequency of adding elements into it, then I have to choose binary search. Am I right?

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya You're calculating the number of operations incorrectly. Big-O notation just describes the upper bound for algorithmic complexity as `n` changes. You can't just substitute in numbers like that. All you know is that the number of operations taken to sort is bounded by `k n lg n`, where `k` is some constant. Similar thing for O(lg n) and O(n). But in the end, I *think* you have the right idea. One-off searches on an unsorted list, consider linear. Repeated searches on a list, consider binary.

Answer (score 3):

Java's Collections.sort() takes O (n log n) time.  So sort + binary search takes O (n log n) + O (log n).  Compare that with your O (n) linear search.

You may also want to take into account that you only have to sort once.  So if you are searching x times using linear search, you are now taking the O(n log n) Sort and adding x iterations of an O(n) algorithm rather than adding x iterations of an O(log n) algorithm, which is obviously much more costly.

Comment: I really think you should expand on this answer. There is a lot more depth to this answer than Big-O analysis, because Big-O isn't the be-all-and-end-all of deciding what algorithm to choose. Case in point: Search more than `n` times, and linear search starts to get quite expensive.

Comment: @UpAllNight Can you explain with an example of 500 elements in a list?

Comment: Suppose I have 500 elements. The operations taken to sort is 500 log 500. Now I am searching for the element. Its log 500. The total operations are 500 * 2.x + 2.x. Where as, if I am linearly searching it is 500 operations. What I understand is, if the list is always changing, I have to go for linear searching. If the searching is more and with a less frequency of adding elements into it, then I have to choose binary search. Am I right?

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya Yes, that would be the general conclusion.  If you are doing one or two searches on the same list then linear search is faster.  If you are doing three or more searches on the same list, then sort + binary search is faster.

Comment: ONLY IF you hang on to the sorted results.

Answer (score 0):

```
what if I don't want to sort the list?
```

As the documentation is saying

`If it is not sorted, the results are undefined. If the list contains multiple elements equal to the specified object, there is no guarantee which one will be found.`

If you have multiple name that is similar than other in a List then there is on guarantee that it will be found by using the `binarySearch`.

```
an anyone please tell me why should I use binary search instead of manually searching.
```

If you are using an ArrayList that is a `random access` as a List without any duplication of name then it will search in O(log n).

here is the **documentation**:

```
This method runs in log(n) time for a "random access" list (which provides near-constant-time positional access).
```

hence if you are using a List that is not a `randon access` ex. `LinkedList` then it will search with a speed of `O(n)`

```
If the specified list does not implement the RandomAccess interface and is large, this method 
will do an iterator-based binary search that performs O(n) link traversals and O(log n) element
comparisons.
```

Comment: OP already read the documentation. Not to be rude, but I don't see the point of quoting more documentation at him, without any actual suggestions.